# Auto-resize @Html.EditorFor (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have `@Html.EditorFor` , here is code. I need it to resize on height when I enter text.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.question, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Вопрос" } })
```

How I can do this?

Comment: What template is the EditorFor using? A `input[type="text"]`? A `textarea`? A custom template? You will need to do this in javascript more than likely... what have you tried?

Comment: custom css class @zgood